# Equality of Lower and Upper Darboux sums

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a bounded function for which
>   there is a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ with $L(f,P)=U(f,P).$ Show that
>   $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a constant function.

**My attempt:**
$$L(f,P)=U(f,P)\implies \sum_{i=1}^n m_i(x_i-x_{i-1})=\sum_{i=1}^n M_i(x_i-x_{i-1})\implies m_i=M_i, i=1,...,n,$$ i.e. $$inf\{f(x)|x \text{ in } [x_{i-1},x_i]\}=sup \{f(x)|x \text{ in } [x_{i-1},x_i]\} \implies f(x) = const \text{ on } [x_{i-1},x_i], i = 1,...,n.$$

Is this right? If so, why do we need f to be bounded then?

Comment: If the function was not bounded then how could you even define Darboux sums? There would be an interval in the partition where either the supremum is infinity or the infimum is negative infinity.

Comment: Your proof needs one more little step to point out that the constant is the same for all intervals.

Comment: @copper.hat we need f to be continuous right? There was no assumption of that in the problem, then can I say that f is continuous?

Comment: @dxdydz: Not a priori. Since the left end of one interval is the same as the right end of the other then the value agrees on the union of the intervals. Hence it is constant and hence continuous.